# How can I increase the number in a input statement loop for Python?

Tags: python, loops

I really need help on this. Trying to create a code that determines the average temperature for an inputted amount of days. I have the input statement correct and converted to int. However, in the loop, I need it to ask the user each time

What temp was it on day X, with X being the the first day and it repeating and increasing the value each time it loops. Please help me anyone.

Here is the code below:

```
#Determine average temperature

days = input("How many days are you entering temperatures for:")
days = int(days)

sum = 0

for i in range(days):
    temperature = input("What temp was it on day?")
    temperature= int(temperature)
    sum = sum + temperature

average_temperature = sum/int(days)
print("Average temperature:", average_temperature)
```

Comment: You already have the number you need (minus 1) in `i`. Just use that.

Comment: `temperature = input(f"What temp was it on day {i+1}?")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a formatted f-string to include a variable in a string as suggested by @JohnGordon:

```
temperature = input(f"What temp was it on day {i + 1}? ")
```

It's usually a good idea to separate input/output and calculations.  It usually also more intuitive to terminate input as you go along instead of asking for a count upfront.  In this case I use enter (i.e. empty string as input) to signify that you are done asking for input:

```
import itertools

temperatures = []
for i in itertools.count(1):
    temperature = input(f"What temp was it on day {i}? ")
    if not temperature:
        break
    temperatures.append(int(temperature))

average_temperature = sum(temperatures) / len(temperatures)

print(f"Average temperature: {average_temperature}")
```

Comment: Yes, but @JohnGordon have used [_f-strings_](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) which is much more up-to-date and considered a better way than formatting using `%`

Comment: Please provide a quote to support your opinion.   I am not saying your are wrong, to me, it's just two different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: you can find some basic explanations [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/#1-old-style-string-formatting-operator).

Comment: Thanks but do you have a python.org (ie authoritative source)?  I will update answer though just for you.

Comment: Yes, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). Take a look at the gray box, immediately after the title. And also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting) they call it "old-style"

Comment: Thanks @ronpi, I appreciate you dug those references up for me.

Comment: Hi thank you so much! This is so helpful, I really appreciate it <3

Comment: Any time, @AmandaBasant, make sure you accept the best answer so we know you are all set.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry new to this website

Comment: @AmandaBasant See the link that I shared with you stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer (i.e. click the check mark icon next to an answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in method str to convert int to str.

```
temperature = input("What temp was it on day "+ str(i+1) + " ? ")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much <3